# returning a local as value/reference

Tags: c++, reference, return-value, local

This Question arises from a Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465851/returning-const-reference-to-local-variable-from-a-function)

I have some doubts that i think cant be asked in the followup comments there, and not too sure if i could have edited the linked question with my doubts...hence a new question.

Firstly,what i learnt from the linked question is that returning ref to local is EVIL!

Now,consider the same example from that question,a bit modified though:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    public:
        int x;
        string s;
        A(int xx,string ss):x(xx),s(ss)
    {
        cout<<"A::A()"<<x<<","<<s<<"\n";
    }
        A(const A& that)
        {
            cout<<"cpy ctr\n";
            x=that.x;
            s=that.s;
        }
        A& operator=(const A& that)
        {
            cout<<"operator=\n";
        }
        ~A()
        {
            cout<<"~A()"<<s<<"\n";
        }
};

const A& getA1()
{
    A a(1,"A1");
    cout<<"returning from A1\n";
    return a;
}

A& getA2()
{
    A a(2,"A2");
    cout<<"returning from A2\n";
    return a;
}

A getA3()
{
    A a(3,"A3");
    cout<<"returning from A3\n";
    return a;
}

int main()
{ 
    A &newA2 = getA2();       //.....................LINE 2
    cout<<"returned from A2\n";
    cout<<"-----------------------------\n";
    A newA3 = getA3();       //......................LINE 3
    //A const  newConstA3 = getA3 ();
    cout<<"returned from A3\n";
    cout<<"-----------------------------\n";
    //cout<<"newA2="<<newA2.x<<","<<newA2.s<<"\n";
    cout<<"newA3="<<newA3.x<<","<<newA3.s<<"\n";

}
```

The output is as follows..

```
A::A()2,A2
returning from A2
~A()A2
returned from A2
-----------------------------
A::A()3,A3
returning from A3
returned from A3
-----------------------------
newA3=3,A3
~A()A3
```

**Now my doubts...**

1. in **LINE 2**, the fun `getA2()` (which returns by ref) returns after destructing the temporary,so the recieving object `newA2` is dangerous to use.(the reason why i have comented out its use.) so then why doesent the fun `getA3()` destruct the temporary even though it returns by "copy" (Note that the temporary's destructor inside `getA3()` doesnt get called ever..only `newA3` object's destructor gets called when it dies at the end of `main()` )? I have no clue where does that temp go??
2. Now if in **LINE 2** i change it from `A& newA2 = getA2();` to `A newA2 = getA2();` ,the copy ctr gets called here(which eventually gives a segfault as the referent has died),but why doesnt the copy ctr gets called at **LINE 3** ? How does the state of the temporary is getting copied into object `newA3`,notice no `operator=()` is being called either ?
3. Lastly.. the output here is from gcc, but does MSVC++2008 work differently??
   As even for the code `A newA3 = getA3();` in **LINE 3** it behaves the same as **LINE 2**,i.e, it destructs the temp before returning! any clues?

Comment: I find the output layout and your questions very hard to follow. Can't you simplify? And, please, one question per question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It appears you are benefiting from [Return Value Optimisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).
2. Because you are copying an, albeit invalid, reference into a new object.
3. MSVC and GCC work broadly the same.  Avoid undefined behaviour (This can be harder than it may seem) and if they don't work the same way then there is a bug in the compiler.

Comment: so.i guess gcc prevails over vc++?

Comment: @ashishsony: TBH post VC6 MSVC has been pretty C++ standard compliant.  I believe things like lambdas and "nullptr" were available in VS 2010 before they were in GCC ...

Comment: @Goz: That makes it _non-compliant_, since 2010 predates C++11 :P

Answer (score 0):

1. Well, of course the value to be returned is not destroyed, otherwise you'd never be able to return anything from a function. I believe it goes straight onto the calling scope's stack after copying it from the local scope.
2. Copy elision. When a copy is excessive (as it would be here), the compiler is allowed to elide it (even if it has side effects) as a sort of standard-prescribed "optimisation". This is documented in many, many questions on SO.
3. It's not clear what you're asking. You haven't shown two pieces of output to compare.

Comment: –1 because it’s wrong, in particular 1. Local variables cease existence at the end of scope, and are destroyed. You are *still* able to return values from a function because the value gets copied (before being destroyed, of course). Copy elision is a different matter entirely (the compiler is allowed this optimisation but it’s only that – an *optimisation* which doesn’t form an argument about semantics) – Who the hell upvoted this?

Comment: @Konrad: Er, what? 1) The value to be returned is not the local variable. It is a copy. I never said otherwise. Quite _obviously_, the value to be returned cannot be destroyed with the local scope... 2) Right, and I said that. That doesn't mean it doesn't affect the output of the program. Can you clarify on your problems with this answer?